# Invalid Toolchain message even though app not submitted with beta software

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to submit a project to the app store. I accidently opened it in the latest Xcode Beta - but did not save or change anything.

I submitted the app with Xcode 7.3.1 and when I attempt to submit the app for review I get the message: `"New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds."`

If I check the Info.plist of the archive it also mentions me using the public version of Xcode

```
<key>DefaultToolchainInfo</key>
<dict>
    <key>DisplayName</key>
    <string>Xcode 7.3.1 Default</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault</string>
</dict>
```

The Xcode beta version was not open when submitting and I also tried restarting and then resubmitting. Btw I am running El Cap 10.11.6

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Same here. Looks like the patch they released yesterday, hasn't been registered in their system.

Comment: I've had the same thing for two submissions today. Probably updating their systems in preperation for the public release of iOS 10 (which I think is on the 7th after their anouncement)

Comment: Same here, after submitting I receive an email with the  "Invalid Toolchain" message. I don't even have Xcode or OS X beta installed.

Comment: I selected gklka's answer since he was the first one to link it to the iTunes team not whitelisting the OS X version after the security update. (I upvoted all the others.) My tip for anyone reading this in the future: Always have a second machine that you update a couple of days later - especially when you are crunching a deadline. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install yesterday's Security Update? I have a theory, that this update altered the internal version number from 10.11.6 (15G31) to 10.11.6 (15G1004), and they have not added this version number to the list of allowed stable OS builds on iTunes Connect.

Comment: yup - installed yesterday's security update. Do you have a link to the list of iTunes Connect stable builds?

Comment: I don't think there is one. I see only two solutions: either we wait until they add this build number (hopefully today), or disable Rootless, change OS X's build number, build the app, upload it, then revert the change.

Comment: I installed the update but my co-worker hadn't done it yet, and when I tried to submit an update but failed. He managed to do it for me and we are now waiting for review.

Comment: I also installed the security update and I can't submit my build

Answer (score 2):

Fairly certain it's the Security Update.

I tried the known hack of altering the OS build to 15G31 in SystemVersion.plist, but this no longer seems to work.
Reinstalling Xcode 7.3.1 was also a waste of time.

Luckily I had a machine that I had not yet done Security Update 2016-001 on.  Moved the code over there, archived and uploaded, and this went fine.

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue and **the issue just got fixed** - I have submitted my app for review successfully 5 minutes ago!

It was because iTunes team did not synchronise with latest macOS version security update yet and they finished synchronisation just now!

Please go ahead and try re-submitting your app!

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing this also, there was a recent security update to El Cap that might be related, or Apple is in the process of making changes for iOS10 Xcode 8 and have messed up something.

If you need to submit, I would go ahead and submit and if you get a rejection, explain it to Apple then.

Comment: You cannot submit, because iTunes Connect reject the build.

Comment: Update to my comment above... I have just been able to submit my app for review although I received this warning.

Comment: @Scriptable how?? I've submitted 3 builds trying to get around this

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, i uploaded to the store, it started processing, i got an email saying there was a problem.. invalid toolchain etc. then it allowed me to select that build and submit for review

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded my iOS binary installing El Capitan on a virtual machine, disabling system updates, installing Xcode, importing my developer profile, and building my App there.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent like 2-3 hours downloading the base El Capitan (10.11.6) from the App Store and setting up VMware Fusion to build our project in... including manually regenerating and switching all of the certificates and provisioning profiles **twice** (to there and back to the host machine).

**I can conclude that this does solve the issue because the App Store El Capitan installer does not (yet) include the Security Update,** which bumps the macOS build number to one that is NOT whitelisted on iTunes Connect, as some have suggested.

Super frustrating, but at least a solution is available for now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html) and see if your version of Xcode has: "Support for app archives depreciated", like mine did.